# How to get a count of the current open sockets in Node?

Tags: node.js, sockets, node-request, node-https

I am using the *request* module to crawl a list of URLs and would like to 
limit the number of open sockets to 2:

```
var req = request.defaults({
   forever: true,
   pool: {maxSockets: 1}
});

req(options, function(error, response, body) {

 ... code ...

 done();
```

however, when looping over an array of URLs and issuing a new request to each - that does not seem to work.

is there a way to get the current number of open sockets to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `maxSockets` maps to [`http.Agent.maxSockets`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets), which limits the number of concurrent requests *to the same origin* (`host:port`).

[This comment](https://github.com/request/request/issues/377#issuecomment-10829541), from the developer of `request`, suggests the same:

> actually, pooling controls the agent passed to core. each agent holds all hosts and throttles the maxSockets *per host*

In other words, you can't use it to limit the number of concurrent requests in general. For that, you need to use an external solution, for instance using [`limiter`](https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter) or [`async.queue`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue).